# NHibernate Getting issue invalid attempt to call read when reader is closed

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I am getting some issue regarding NHibernate batch save.
At the same time i am saving more than 250 entites which are linked through NHibernate mapping.

There is one to many relationship between two entities.

```
ParentEntity 1 
   ----  ChildEntity 1
   ----  ChildEntity 2
   ----  ChildEntity 3
              --
              --
   ----  ChildEntity 249   
   ----  ChildEntity 250   


So when i call 
      repository.save(ParentEntity 1);
```

It will internally call saving for 250 childEntity and 1 ParentEntity. I have already set  batchsize to increase performace. But after some time i will get exception as "invalid attempt to call read when reader is closed".

For detail, i have checked sql queries in the profiler. Till 200 childEntities i can see insert statement but after that reset connection has been called. "exec sp_reset_connection"  i don't no, issue that i am getting of reader closed is because of this reseting connection.

Can anyone please help me out to solve this issue?

THanks,
Mahesh.

Comment: have you tried the nhibernate profiler?

Comment: same problem here - no idea what's causing it.

Comment: Please check !! some where session is losing the connection. Try by setting the property "command_timeout". May insert taking some more time due to huge data ... so connection lost causing "invalid attempt to call read when reader is closed".